# React form - Can I apply mode onSubmit to some field and to other fields onBlur mode?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-forms

Im using react form and want to apply validation with mode onBlur to all fields except when I compare passwords (password and password confirmation field). As of now as is the field where I type the password again is the last field in my form, onBlur wouldnt help, so I use watch. The problem is that the err (passwords dont match) is shown immidiatly while typing which I dont want. So the submit button should stay disabled as long as there are any errors (mode onBlur), but become enabled after. Then I want the err 'passwords dont match' to be shown only when user clicks the submit button. Is that possible?

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
        .required('emailRequired')
        .email('invalidEmail'),
    password: Yup.string()
        .required('passwordRequired')
        .min(PASSWORD_MIN, 'minlengthPassword')
        .max(PASSWORD_MAX, 'maxlengthPassword'),
    confirmedPassword: Yup.string()
        .test((value, context) => {
            if (value !== context.parent.password) {
                return context.createError({ message: 'passwordNoMatch' })
            }
            return true;
        })
});
const App = () => {
     const {
        watch,
        getValues,
        control,
        handleSubmit,
        trigger,
        clearErrors,
        formState: {errors, isValid}
    } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
        mode: 'onTouched',
        defaultValues: {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            email: "",
            password: "",
            confirmedPassword: "",
            lang: i18n.language
        }
    });
  return (
     ...
           <Controller
                control={control}
                name="email"
                render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
                   <FormInput
                      name="email"
                      secureTextEntry={false}
                      trigger={trigger}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      value={value}
                      errors={errors}
                      clearErrors={clearErrors}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
       ...
       {watch("confirmedPassword") !== watch("password") &&
                    getValues("confirmedPassword") ? (
                        <Text style={styles.pwdNoMatch}>{t('confirmedPwdNoMatch', {ns: 'errors'})}</Text>
                    ) : null}
  )
}
```

Comment: Please create the minimal example using Expo Snack